# Grid alignment automatically into multiple rows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like have it such that I can specify one row but have the program automatically split the result into multiple rows if required. I need to do it this way as I dynamic div content being populated so it needs to properly align accordingly. I am using bootstrap 3.

```
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <div>one</div>
      <div>two</div>
      <div>three</div>
      <div>four</div>
      <div>five</div>
      <div>six</div>
      <div>seven</div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

End result would be: "one", "two", "three" on the first row.
"four", "five", "six" on the second row. "seven" on the third row.

Basically what I am looking for is a way for the bootstrap to automatically align with at most divs per row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood everything correctly you're using bootstrap not in the right way.

Every bootstrap `row` has 12 columns. These columns can be grouped.
Now you can group these columns for each device. [Read more on the bootstrap 3 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-options).
For example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    one
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    two
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    three
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    four
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    five
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    six
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    seven
  </div>
 </div>
```

This code aligns each number text (one, two, three ...) according to the size of your col-**XX**-Y. So on medium `md` sizes, you got 3 columns. On small `sm` sizes you have 2 columns etc. 
This is based on the 12 columns (on total) *divided* by the number you specified in the `col-XX-Y` class.

Just remember:

> The XX represents the screenwidth and the Y represents the columns you
>   want to group at this screenwidth.